# Ruby Scripts - Reference Gems

Tags: ruby

I am writing my first ruby script and am curious how to actually have gem referenced in the script. I am unable to test the code before hand because it reads form an email in **`/etc/aliases`** through a pipe. 
Any one one with experiences with ruby scripts to advise?
P.S So many bugs because not tested or refactored

Sample Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# Reading files
mail = File.open(ARGV[0])
lines = []
mail.each_with_index do |i,line|
  line[i] = lines.#remove leading and trailing spaces
end
first_line = line[1].strip
if line[1] /^(256)/
   phone_number = first_line.gsub("+", "")
else
   phone_number = "256#{first_line.gsub(/^0+/,"")}"
end

message = line[2].strip

# Sending message
url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/v2/json/messages?token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&to=#{phone_number}&from=XXXXXX&message=#{CGI.escape(message)}"
5.times do |i|
  response = HTTParty.get(url)
  body = JSON.parse(response.body)
  if body["status"] == "Success"
    break
  end
end
```

Gems in question are CGI, Httparty, and Json parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Using external gems can be done by calling the "require" method.

So to include them in your script, the first few lines could be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "json"
require "cgi"
require "httparty"

#rest of your code...
```

I assume you have installed your gems with `gem install <gemname>`?

Comment: There is no `require` keyword in Ruby, as you can easily see by checking the [list of keywords](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/keywords.rdoc).